# Block LAN allow Internet on debian eth0<->wlan0 sharing (LAN Isolated Guest WiFi AP)

Tags: iptables, wifi-hotspot

At home (192.168.x.x) with various routers and servers, I have set up an WiFI AP using eth0<->wlan0 sharing, as Guest WiFi.

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Clients that connect to wlan0 should have internet access but all other traffic from and to any other address on 192.168.x.x should be dropped. 
How can I specify this in iptables?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `physdev` module is for:

`-A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in wlan0 --physdev-out eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @ECII What shall I explain about that? `-i` and `-o` do not work with bridged interfaces thus you need physdev; simple as that. `man iptables-extensions`